# jQuery Dialog : What is a jQuery dialog, is it a separate webpage or is it part of the existing webpage?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

Whats the meaning of Jquery dialog:
Is it separate web page or its part of web page?

(I don't know well Jquery).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery dialog will appear above the page but it is effectively part of the current page. When your loading a dialog you are loading a element in the DOM (Document Object Model, the HTML elements on your page) which will appear as a pop-up 'dialog' on top of the current page.

You can however load other pages, or content, into a dialog. When the dialog is opened you would make a call to the server to either include another page or load new content. In both cases you would normally be inserting this into the dom element on the *current page* which holds content for the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

It is part of the existing page, dynamically displayed via javascript.

Gives the appearance of a smaller window overlaying the current page, but in actuality, it is just another element within the page.

It can have characteristics that resemble a window, like the ability to move, resize and close.

See demos and documentation here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/